# Logo Centering in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, position, centering

This is my wordpress website and I'm trying to move my logo in center.

https://sunnongdanusa.com/

I've tried their attribute and position, but its not working and need help

please help me to change logo position only in mobile view

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the style rule which is causing the problem. Comment out this rule and I think you'll find your issue is resolved.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1159px) {
  .mobile-logo-right #header-responsive .header-right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
just wonder Do you know how to comment that out from Wordpress? or How to mute them ?

Comment: If you can’t comment it out then override it. Go to Customise > Additional CSS and paste the rule in as above, but change `display: none` to `display: initial`.

Comment: It works! thank you for your help it was my first wordpress site project and did not know its simple like this Thank you